Trouble with Sqrt Function/Program in MIPS Assembly
I'm working on converting a C program that finds the sqrt via a binary search to MIPS assembly and I am struggling. I believe that my program essentially is iterating one less time through the while loop than it should. For example, for the sqrt(16), it returns 8 and for sqrt(4) it returns 4. Here is the original C code I am trying to convert:
#include <stdio.h>

float fsqrt(float x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;

    float xhi = x;
    float xlo = 0;
    float guess = x / 2;
    float error = 0;

    error = guess * guess - x;

    if (error < 0) {
        error = 0 - error;
    }

    while (error > 0.00001) {
        if (guess * guess > x) {
            xhi = guess;
        } else {
            xlo = guess;
        }

        guess = (xhi + xlo) / 2;
        error = guess * guess - x;

        if (error < 0) {
            error = 0 - error;
        }
    }

    return guess;
}

int main() {
    float number;
    printf("Enter a non-negative number: ");
    scanf("%f", &number);
    printf("Square root is %.6f\n", fsqrt(number));
    return 0;
}


I've tried saving the output number to the stack at different points to no avail. I had it working for sqrt(16) at one point but noticed multiple errors and am essentially back to square one. I will note I compile and run via QtSpim. Any help or guidance is appreciated! Here is my current MIPS code:
    .data
float0: .float 0.0 # For comparing floats to 0
errorCheck: .float 0.00001 # Error margin for correct sqrt
enterText: .asciiz "Enter a non-negative number: "
outputText: .asciiz "Square root is "
newLine: .asciiz "\n"

    .text
main:
    # Request number
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, enterText
    syscall

    # Read number (float)
    li $v0, 6
    syscall
    s.s $f0, 0($sp) # Save number to 0 on stack
   
    # Calculate square root
    jal fsqrt
   
    # Print square root text
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, outputText
    syscall
   
    # Print square root number
    li $v0, 2
    l.s $f12, 4($sp)
    syscall
   
    # Print new line
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall
   
    # Exit program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
   
fsqrt:
    l.s $f0, 0($sp)      # Load input number into $f0(x) from stack
    l.s $f31, float0     # Load float0 into $f31
    li.s $f29, 2.0       # Load 2.0  into $f29 for divisor
    l.s $f28, errorCheck # Load error check into $f28 for checking error
    
    # Increase stack for output/return (Return will be saved to 4($sp))
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    
    # Return 0 if input == 0
    c.eq.s $f0, $f31
    bc1t return0
    
    mov.s $f1, $f0       # Load x into "xhi"
    mov.s $f2, $f31      # Load 0 into "xlo"
    div.s $f3, $f0, $f29 # Load x/2 into "guess"
    mov.s $f4, $f31      # Load 0 into "error"
    
    mul.s $f30, $f3, $f3 # Load guess^2 into $f30 temporarily
    sub.s $f4, $f30, $f0 # error = guess^2 - x
    
    # Error = -Error if less than 0
    c.lt.s $f4, $f31
    bc1t errorLTZero
    
    j while

while:
    # If error > 0.00001, end loop (exit function)
    c.le.s $f4, $f28
    bc1f exitFunc
    
    mul.s $f30, $f3, $f3 # Loads guess^2 into $f30 for conditional
        
    # if guess^2 < x, xlo = guess
    c.lt.s $f30, $f0
    bc1t guessSqLTx
        
    # else xhi = guess
    mov.s $f1, $f3
        
    add.s $f30, $f1, $f2  # Load "xhi + xlo" into temp float register
    div.s $f3, $f30, $f29  # Load "xhi + xlo / 2" into guess
    
    mul.s $f30, $f3, $f3 # Load guess^2 into $f30 temporarily
    sub.s $f4, $f30, $f0 # Load "guess - x" into $f30 temporarily+
    
    # Error = -Error if less than 0
    c.lt.s $f4, $f31
    bc1t errorLTZero    
        
    s.s $f3, 4($sp) # Save guess to stack
        
    j while
    
j exitFunc

return0: 
    s.s $f31, 4($sp)
    jr $ra
        
errorLTZero:
    sub.s $f4, $f31, $f4
    jr $ra
    
exitFunc:
    s.s $f3, 4($sp)
    jr $ra

guessSqLTx:
    mov.s $f2, $f3
    jr $ra


Use your debugger/simulator to single step the code and see where it goes wrong.

Your errorLTZero ends with a jr $ra but it is not called as a function. Hence it will cause an early return from fsqrt.

You should branch to some local locations inside your function and swap a wrong branch condition. You probably need a special case for input 1 because it's not yielding 1.0 as a result but 0.9999962.
    .data
float0: .float 0.0 # For comparing floats to 0
errorCheck: .float 0.00001 # Error margin for correct sqrt
two: .float 2.0 # For comparing floats to 0
enterText: .asciiz "Enter a non-negative number: "
outputText: .asciiz "Square root is "
newLine: .asciiz "\n"

    .text
main:
    # Request number
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, enterText
    syscall

    # Read number (float)
    li $v0, 6
    syscall
    s.s $f0, 0($sp) # Save number to 0 on stack
   
    # Calculate square root
    jal fsqrt
   
    # Print square root text
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, outputText
    syscall
   
    # Print square root number
    li $v0, 2
    l.s $f12, 4($sp)
    syscall
   
    # Print new line
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall
   
    # Exit program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
   
fsqrt:
    l.s $f0, 0($sp)      # Load input number into $f0(x) from stack
    l.s $f31, float0     # Load float0 into $f31
    l.s $f29, two       # Load 2.0  into $f29 for divisor
    l.s $f28, errorCheck # Load error check into $f28 for checking error
    
    # Increase stack for output/return (Return will be saved to 4($sp))
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    
    # Return 0 if input == 0
    c.eq.s $f0, $f31
    bc1t return0
    
    mov.s $f1, $f0       # Load x into "xhi"
    mov.s $f2, $f31      # Load 0 into "xlo"
    div.s $f3, $f0, $f29 # Load x/2 into "guess"
    mov.s $f4, $f31      # Load 0 into "error"
    
    mul.s $f30, $f3, $f3 # Load guess^2 into $f30 temporarily
    sub.s $f4, $f30, $f0 # error = guess^2 - x
    
    # Error = -Error if less than 0
    c.lt.s $f4, $f31
    bc1t errorLTZero
    
    j while

while:
    # If error > 0.00001, end loop (exit function)
    c.le.s $f4, $f28
    bc1t exitFunc
    
    mul.s $f30, $f3, $f3 # Loads guess^2 into $f30 for conditional
        
    # if guess^2 < x, xlo = guess
    c.lt.s $f30, $f0
    bc1t guessSqLTx
        
    # else xhi = guess
    mov.s $f1, $f3
    b guessSqLTxCont
guessSqLTx:
    mov.s $f2, $f3
guessSqLTxCont:
        
    add.s $f30, $f1, $f2  # Load "xhi + xlo" into temp float register
    div.s $f3, $f30, $f29  # Load "xhi + xlo / 2" into guess
    
    mul.s $f30, $f3, $f3 # Load guess^2 into $f30 temporarily
    sub.s $f4, $f30, $f0 # Load "guess - x" into $f4 temporarily+
    
    # Error = -Error if less than 0
    c.lt.s $f4, $f31
    bc1t errorLTZero    
    b errorLTZeroCont
errorLTZero:
    sub.s $f4, $f31, $f4
errorLTZeroCont:
        
    s.s $f3, 4($sp) # Save guess to stack
        
    j while
    
j exitFunc

return0: 
    s.s $f31, 4($sp)
    jr $ra
        
exitFunc:
    s.s $f3, 4($sp)
    jr $ra

